# Desktop client working with DB - direct connection or proxy (WCF)?

Tags: c#, database, wcf, architecture

First of all, I am not a programmer anymore but like to stay in touch with development. I would like to develop a simple system for my teamm embers to log their work and additional data. Basically, I need every member to use a desktop app which will basically login to DB and allow to do CRUD operations. I can think of two approaches:

1. Having a desktop app with harcoded (or configurable) db connection string and for every user an account would have to be created. So basically login into the system would mean logging into a database with given usesrname
2. Having a desktop app communicating with WCF service that would handle all the database connections, so DB root account could be used with a simple table of users.

The first point is apparently much easier as it is basically just connecting to the database but I am not sure about security issue there.

Comment: WCF isn't going to magically solve any security issues here, and if anything, making the project more complex won't help keep it secure.
Using WCF, you would be pumping authentication requests and data over the wire via your *own* protocol rather than the one developed by your database connector provider, making you responsible for end-to-end encryption.

Comment: Thanks. I thought WCF communication is somehow secured and at least I would not be stored database credentials inside the application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Web API instead of WCF. I've found Web API *much* easier to develop for and consume. Plus you can secure Web API over HTTPS - easy peasy.

Regardless, Timothy Groote's point is apt: you would need to secure access to your Web service layer. There are ways to do that, certainly - starting from transmitting authentication in the HTTP headers (encrypted using SSL, of course) and going all the way to setting up an OAuth provider.

If this is a simple system, I would vote for option 1. This choice will limit your flexibility and expandability, but that may be the right tradeoff in this simple case.

If you're going to use option 1, can you use integrated security to connect to the DB? This would mean you don't have to store credentials in your connection string. If you can't use integrated security, then you could look into encrypting the connection string. However, you may not need to - if this is going to be a limited-release app, and users are generally trustworthy, then is it actually a problem if a user knows *their own* DB connection information?